# change function to accept multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, function

I need to modify the functions below to accept multiple arguments instead of only 4 arguments, I have been able to modify the first function `UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT` successfully, however I am not able to modify `UseJstsToDissolveGeometries` as I am unsure how to loop through the arguments and assign a variable name to be used later in the function and I also get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'union' of undefined`

How can I modify `UseJstsToDissolveGeometries` to accept multiple arguments?

```
function UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(poly1,poly2,poly3,poly4) {
   var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();

   wicket.fromObject(poly1);
   var wkt1 = wicket.write();

   wicket.fromObject(poly2);
   var wkt2 = wicket.write();

   wicket.fromObject(poly3);
   var wkt3 = wicket.write();

   wicket.fromObject(poly4);
   var wkt4 = wicket.write();

   return [wkt1, wkt2, wkt3, wkt4];
}

function UseJstsToDissolveGeometries(wkt1, wkt2, wkt3, wkt4) {
  // Instantiate JSTS WKTReader and get two JSTS geometry objects
  var wktReader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
  var geom1 = wktReader.read(wkt1);
  var geom2 = wktReader.read(wkt2);
  var geom3 = wktReader.read(wkt3);
  var geom4 = wktReader.read(wkt4);

  // In JSTS, "union" is synonymous with "dissolve"

  var dissolvedGeometry;
  dissolvedGeometry = geom2.union(geom1);
  dissolvedGeometry = dissolvedGeometry.union(geom3);
  dissolvedGeometry = dissolvedGeometry.union(geom4);

  // Instantiate JSTS WKTWriter and get new geometry's WKT

  var wktWriter = new jsts.io.WKTWriter();
  var wkt = wktWriter.write(dissolvedGeometry);

  // Use Wicket to ingest the new geometry's WKT

  var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();
  wicket.read(wkt);
}

function DoEverything() {
   var wkt = UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(polygon6, polygon7,polygon8, polygon9);
   UseJstsToDissolveGeometries(wkt[0], wkt[1], wkt[2], wkt[3]);
}
```

My attempt

```
function UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(...args) {
   var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();
   return args.map(item => {
     wicket.fromObject(item);
     return wicket.write();
   })
}

function UseJstsToDissolveGeometries(...args) {
  var wktReader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
  args.map(item => {
    return wktReader.read(item);
  })

  var dissolvedGeometry;
  args.map(item => {
    return dissolvedGeometry = dissolvedGeometry.union(item)
  })

  var wktWriter = new jsts.io.WKTWriter();
  var wkt = wktWriter.write(dissolvedGeometry);

  // Use Wicket to ingest the new geometry's WKT
  var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();
  wicket.read(wkt);
}

function DoEverything() {
   var wkt = UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(polygon6, polygon7,polygon8, polygon9);
   UseJstsToDissolveGeometries(wkt[0], wkt[1], wkt[2], wkt[3]);
}
```

Comment: `var geom =  args.map(item => {
    return wktReader.read(item);
  })

  var dissolvedGeometry;
  geom.map(item => {
    return dissolvedGeometry = dissolvedGeometry.union(item)
  })`

Comment: @Satpal That's a weird thing to do, why not reduce the array instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for *something* like this, the problem is you're using 
`dissolvedGeometry` before it's been defined

```
function UseJstsToDissolveGeometries(...args) {
  var wktReader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
  var geoms = args.map(item => {
    return wktReader.read(item);
  })

  var dissolvedGeometry = geoms.reduce((accumulator , item, currentIndex, array) => {
    if (currentIndex == 0) {
      return array[1].union(item);
    }

    if(currentIndex == 1){
      return accumulator;
    }

    return accumulator.union(item)
  })

  var wktWriter = new jsts.io.WKTWriter();
  var wkt = wktWriter.write(dissolvedGeometry);

  // Use Wicket to ingest the new geometry's WKT
  var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();
  wicket.read(wkt);
}
```

Also, you need the result from the `.map`. Also as you only want one result in dissolvedGeometry, I think a `.reduce` would be better

**P.S** as I don't actually know what these objects produce, what methods they have etc, this code might not *work* but will give you the idea on what to do to get it to work

Comment: thanks George that certainly gives me something to work with , I get the error Uncaught ReferenceError: currrentIndex is not defined when using your code

Comment: @tomharrison Yeah my bad, put too many `r`'s in the second `if` :) Edited it now

Comment: thanks a million this works exactly as I need it to :D